# PHP FastCGI Simple Counter

Tags: php, perl, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I am unable to understand and run a simple PHP script in FCGI mode. I am learning both Perl and PHP and I got the Perl version of FastCGI example below to work as expected.

Perl FastCGI counter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FCGI;

$count = 0;

while (FCGI::accept() >= 0) {

    print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n",
          "<title>FastCGI Hello! (Perl)</title>\n",
          "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (Perl)</h1>\n",
          "Request number ", $++count,
          " running on host <i>$ENV('SERVER_NAME')</i>");

}
```

Searching for similar in PHP found talk about "fastcgi_finish_request" but have no clue how
to accomplish the counter example in PHP, here is what I tried:

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/html");
$counter++;
echo "Counter: $counter ";
//http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.fpm.php
fastcgi_finish_request(); //If you remove this line, then you will see that the browser has to wait 5 seconds
sleep(5);
?>
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't with PHP, it does not allow you the same kind of access as Perl does to the FCGI state. You have to store `$count` between requests in an atomic manner, e.g. update + 1 via a database query while fetching the result earlier and doing $count + 1 for display reasons only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is not PHP. This must not mean that you can not most often interchange things and port code between the two, however when it comes to runtime environments there are bigger differences you can not just interchange.

FCGI is on the request / protocol level already which is fully abstracted in the PHP runtime and you therefore have not as much control in PHP as you would have with Perl and `use FCGI;`

Therefore you can not just port that code.

Next to that [`fastcgi_finish_request`](http://php.net/fastcgi_finish_request) is totally unrelated to the Perl code. You must have confused it or thrown it in by sheer luck to give it a try. However it's not really useful in this counter example context.

Comment: I understand in Perl on the first request Apache/mod_fcgid will load the script and keep it in memory complied for next requests. How does this works in PHP, is it once I call the php script it is compiled once and stayed in memory for next requests starting at the first line in the script normal. What is the benefit of using the php function `fastcgi_finish_request` in the script, is it all I need in my php script to make it ready for FCGI.

Comment: FCGI works both the same as it's a protokol / way of working. However with Perl I can program it all as with PHP it's a feature I use. The PHP SAPI does shed away a lot of the details which are fully available in Perl because the "SAPI" in Perl is just fully written in Perl. `fastcgi_finish_request ` does what is documented on the PHP manual page. If you don't understand what is written there, then you most likely do not need it. In short it allows you to send a response to the browser before the script finishes.

Comment: I started to understand that `fastcgi_finish_request` will send the output to the browser immediately, but my question, will the php script end or will stay in memory compiled ready for the next request. I mean what I need to do to make a regular php script run as a FCGI script. do I need something to be configured on the apache sever itself to distingiush between regular php script and fcgi php script.

Comment: @daliaessam: PHP is shared nothing, even in FCGI. Part of the runtime stays in memory but not your script.

Comment: If my php script does not stay compiled in memory among requests so what is the benefit of using FCGI? As I understand in FCGI mode the scripts should be compiled once and stayed in memory ready for next requests.

Comment: well, it might even do so, however the request and execution is always new. So it might have been parsed into bytecode, but it's not yet executed. But I do not precisely know where PHP FCGI draws the line. I know that part of the script at least is kept in memory, but more for the runtime and not for the scripts state.

Answer (score 1):

PHP and HTTP are stateless.
All data is only relevant for the current, ongoing request.
If you need to save state, you might consider storing the data into cookie, session, cache or db.

So the implementation of this "counter" example will be different for PERL and PHP.

Your usage of `fastcgi_finish_request` won't bring the functionality you expect from PERL.
Think about a long running calculation, where you output data in the middle.
You can do that with fastcgi_finish_request, the data is then pushed to the browsers, while the long running tasks keeps running.

Opening happens together FASTCGI+PHP.
Normally the connection would be open till PHP finishes, then FASTCGI would be closed.
Except you reach the exec timeout of PHP (exec timeout) or fastcgi timeout (connection timeout). fastcgi_finish_request handles the case, where the fascgi connection to the browser is closed BEFORE PHP finishes execution.

**Simple Hit Counter Example for PHP**

```
<?php
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt'); // read count from file
$hit_count++; // increment hit count by 1

echo $hit_count; //  display

@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count); // store the new hit count
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, that's not even how you should do it using Perl either.

Instead, I'd recommend using [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession) to track session information:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI::Session;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new($q) or die CGI->Session->errstr;
print $session->header();

# Page View Count
my $count = 1 + ($session->param('count') // 0);
$session->param('count' => $count);

# HTML
print qq{<html>
<head><title>Hello! (Perl)</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello! (Perl)</h1>
<p>Request number $count running on host <i>$ENV{SERVER_NAME}</i></p>
</body>
</html>};
```

Alternatively, if you really want to go barebones, you could keep a local file as demonstrated in: [`I still don't get locking. I just want to increment the number in the file. How can I do this?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#I-still-don%27t-get-locking.-I-just-want-to-increment-the-number-in-the-file.-How-can-I-do-this%3f)

Comment: My goal was to understand the logic of how PHP works in FCGI mode which seem to be totally different as I see and not to build a counter.

Comment: Roger that, I recognize that this was more of an exploration into PHP.  I just wanted to point out that method of saving state in perl isn't really how it's done either, so trying to match that would be a little misguided.  Good luck